# Scatter plot with point size and color based on dataframe column

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn, scatter-plot

I would like to make a scatter plot in seaborn/matplotlib where the size of points is determined by values in another column (it is TVD(depth) in this case. Then, the colors of points are separated by values in another column (LOF Type)
Columns here are ["Pc","ISIP","TVD","LOF Type"]. The graph would look like this
[Pc-ISIP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ego4D.png)

Comment: please post a sample of you df and what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the color separation you desire comes from a categorical column in your dataframe. I'd solve it to iterate through sliced dataframes:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,1,2,3,4],'y':[2,4,3,7,5],
                   'weight':[2,4,8,5,6],'catnum':[2,3,5,1,7],
                   'catc':['car','car','bike','bike','truck']})

# regular example without categorical:
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
size = 5 * df['weight'].to_numpy()**2
ax1.scatter(df.x,df.y,c=df.catnum,s=size)
fig1.suptitle('numerical demo')
plt.show()

# function to iterate through your categorical column
def _getItr(data,key):
    kinds = sorted(data[key].unique())
    itr = {}
    for i in range(len(kinds)):
        itr[i]=data[data[key]==kinds[i]]
    return itr, kinds


cf, cats = _getItr(df,'catc')

fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()
for c in cf:
    ax2.scatter(cf[c]['x'],cf[c]['y'],s=(5 * cf[c]['weight'].to_numpy()**2),label=cats[c])
    
legend2 = ax2.legend()
for h in legend2.legendHandles: h.set_sizes([30.0])   # otherwize markers in legend have different size
fig2.suptitle('colors and legend from categorical')
plt.show()
```

[example fig2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnVtd.png)